# Check if the email is taken through Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which check if the email typed is available or not, the validity works fine, i get the right error message if the email is taken. If not, i don't have any message which is great... My issue is just that the typed email (when the email is taken) is kept in the user scope variable when the validation fails. This is not the case when the field is empty or the format of the email is not valid (which is exactly what i want for the emailAvailable directive as well). Can you please guys explain me what i missed ?

Html :

```
<div class="col-md-12 wow fadeIn">
    <div class="md-form">
        <div class="md-form">
            <input type="text" 
                    name="email"
                    ng-model="user.email" 
                    ng-pattern="emailFormat"
                    email-available 
                    required
                    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" class="form-control">
            <label for="email" class="">Email</label>
              <span ng-if="userRegistration.$pending.emailTaken" class="text-success">Vérification....</span>
              <div ng-if="userRegistration.$error.emailTaken" class="text-danger">Adresse email déjà prise.</div>
              <div ng-show="userRegistration.$submitted || userRegistration.email.$touched">
                <div ng-show="userRegistration.email.$error.required" class="text-danger">Vous devez indiquer votre email.</div>
              </div>
              <div ng-show="userRegistration.email.$error.pattern" class="text-danger">
                    Votre adresse e-mail n'est pas valide.
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular JS

```
    website.directive('emailAvailable', function($timeout, $q, $http, RESOURCE_API) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) { 

          model.$asyncValidators.emailTaken = function() { 

            return $http({ method: 'POST', url: RESOURCE_API + '/users/checkEmail', 
            headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, data : {'email': elm.val()} })
            .then(function(result) {
              $timeout(function(){
                model.$setValidity('emailTaken', false); 
                if (result.data.data.check == 1) { 
                    // Email Taken, Validation Failed
                    model.$setValidity('emailTaken', false); 
                } else {
                    model.$setValidity('emailTaken', true); 
                }
              }, 1000);
            });
          };
        }
      } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning the rejected promise, so the model validator doesn't know if the validation failed. I made an example with $q. See [this plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/ukeMgd?p=preview) You can see that the model is empty for the rejected promise.

```
      model.$asyncValidators.emailTaken = function(modelValue) { 
            var deferred = $q.defer();
           if(modelValue === 'test') {  // Email Taken, Validation Failed
                deferred.reject();
            } else {
                deferred.resolve('success');
            }
            return deferred.promise;
          };
      }
```